# getJSON JSON Array - Search Functionality Crashing Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I'm running into a problem when trying to add in the search functionality, showList().

It seems to bog down the client so much that Chrome wants to kill the page each time I type into the input field. I'm clearly a novice JS writer, so could I be running an infinite loop somewhere I don't see? Also, any advice to get the search functionality working properly would be hugely appreciated. I don't think I'm using the correct selectors below for the show/hide if statement, but I can't think what else to use.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    showList();
    searchBar();
   
});

function showList() {
  $("#show-records").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
      var json = data;
      $("show-list").append("<table class='specialists'>")
      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
       var obj = json[i],
        tableFormat = "</td><td>";
    
       $("#show-list").append("<tr><td class=1>" + 
        obj.FIELD1 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD2 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD3 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD4 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD5 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD6 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD7 + tableFormat + 
        obj.FIELD8 + "</td></tr>");
    $("show-list").append("</table>");
   }
   //end getJSON inner function
  });
  //end click function
    });
  //end showList()
};



function searchBar() {

 //AJAX getJSON
 $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
  //gathering json Data, sticking it into var json
  var json = data;
  for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   //putting the json objects into var obj
   var obj = json[i];
   function contains(text_one, text_two) {
    if (text_one.indexOf(text_two) != -1)
     return true;
   }
   //whenever anything is entered into search bar...
   $('#search').keyup(function(obj) {
    //grab the search bar content values and...
    var searchEntry = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    //grab each td and check to see if it contains the same contents as var searchEntry - if they dont match, hide; otherwise show
    $("td").each(function() {
     if (!contains($(this).text().toLowerCase(), searchEntry)) {
      $(this).hide(400);
     } else {
      $(this).show(400);
     };
       })
      })
  }
 });
};
```

```css
body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
tr:first-child {
 font-weight: bold;
}
td {
 padding: 3px;
 /*margin: 10px;*/
 text-align: center;
}
td:nth-child(6) {

 padding-left: 50px;
}
td:nth-child(7) {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
#filter-count {
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="process.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <a href="#" id='show-records'>Show Records</a><br>
  <label id="searchBar">Search: <input id="search" placeholder="Enter Specialist Name"></label>
  <span id="search-count"></span>
  <div id="show-list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears to be that you can't treat `append` as if it was a text editor and you are writing html.

Anything that gets inserted needs to be a proper element ... not a start tag, then some text...then a close tag.

We can  however modify your code slightly to produce html strings and then add that at the end

```
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
        var json = data;
        var html="<table class='specialists'>")
        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var obj = json[i],
                tableFormat = "</td><td>";

            html+= "<tr><td class=1>" + 
                obj.FIELD1 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD2 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD3 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD4 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD5 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD6 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD7 + tableFormat + 
                obj.FIELD8 + "</td></tr>";

        }

         html+= '</table>';
        $("#show-list").html(html);
        //end getJSON inner function
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't realize I was misusing ,append(). However, while this does work, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to stop the browser from crashing when I use the searchBar() function.

Comment: how many items are you returning in response? Also are you doing it on every key stroke?

Comment: Also noticing that the source is a static json file , is that real or is data returned based on data sent to server?

Comment: I'm using a static json file, yeah. It's rather large, with about 11,200 lines of JSON. Does that mean it's querying all of that at each keystroke?

Comment: yes definitely it is...and there is no filtering of that data being done. Need to load the data once. Then use a `debounce` on key event so a search isn't done until user stops typing  ... maybe 150 to 200 ms....then filter the data array before creating html